# Stride usage in Conv1D

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

It is my first time trying to use Conv1D in time-series data. I understand that by default the strides for conv1d is 1. But if I have a data of size 1500x9 and I used 32 filters of size 250 and with stride 9.

I tried to search on a lot of sources but didn't get a good explanation. If I used 9 as stride value, my ´model.summary()´ looks like [image]

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(32,250,padding='same',input_shape=(1500,9), 
kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
c1 = MaxPooling1D(2)
model.add(c1)
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
```

If I used stride = 1, then the model.summary() looks like this [image]

How would it work? I would be glad if someone could explain this.

Answer (score 2):

it beacuse of the gradients for example if you compute:

```
input shape:[batch,1500,9]
filtershape:[32,9,250]
stride:1
```

if padding="same" it aplies filter to every 32 in 1500 with sweeping 1 by 1 in this case optimizer asocietes filter with 1500(int(1500/1)) process's gradients
but if you set the stride as 9 then it aplies filter to every 32 in 1500 with sweeping 9 by 9 when you do this optimizer asocietes filter with 166(int(1500/9)) process's gradients

166 process's gradients are easier to deal with than 1500. by doing this you break the correlation between the outputs. its became easier to optimeze but this does not mean that the accuracy value will be higher.

if you want to understand better i suggest you to read this doc:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/nn#Convolution

Comment: I have already read this document. Like I posted the question, I am unable to understand the difference in model's performance when I select stride=1 and stride=9. I understand that when we choose higher value of stride, it skips values. But why such a difference in the model's performance. The model with stride=1 doesn't perform well but the one with stride=9 performs really well.

Comment: @Gafa you didn't ask for the background of a change in performance, only how stride works.